# How to show that all sequentially compact spaces are bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-writing

I want to show given a sequentially compact subset $A \subseteq M \implies A$ is bounded. I read this [Every sequentially compact set is closed and bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226416/every-sequentially-compact-set-is-closed-and-bounded) but the proof is poorly written and jumpy

> Def: $A$ is sequentially compact if every sequence has a convergent
>   subsequence.

- By contradiction, assume $A$ is a sequentially compact subset of $M$
  and $A$ is not bounded.

  Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence on $A$.

  Since $A$ is not bounded, then $\exists a \in A$ such that $\forall r
     > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, d(x_n, a) > r$.

  Let $(x_{n_k})$ be a subsequence of $(x_n)$, then $\exists x \in A$
  such that $x_{n_k} \to x$ as $k \to \infty$

  Then $d(x_{n_k}, x) \leq d(x,a) + d(a, x_{n_k})$ (want to obtain some
  sort of contradiction)

> How do I proceed from here? I know that $d(a, x_{n_k})> r$, but $d(x,a)$ is
>   unknown....

Comment: I think you want to edit your definition of a sequentially compact set. It should be every *sequence* has a convergent sequence. Your statement is a tautology (i.e. every convergent sequence *is* the convergent sub-sequence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $A$ is unbounded.

Let $a \in A$. Then for each $n$ there exists some $x_n$ such that 
$$d(x_n,a) >n$$

Now, $x_n$ has a converging subsequence $x_{k_n} \to b$.

Now, for $\epsilon=1$, since $x_{k_n} \to b$ there exists some $N$ so that for all $n >N$ we have
$$d(x_{k_n}, b) <1$$

Then, for all $n >N$ we have
$$d(a,b) \geq d(a, x_{k_n})-d(b,x_{k_n}) \geq k_n-1 \geq n-1$$

This leads to a contradiction, as $d(a,b)$ is a real number which is larger than any $n >N$.

Comment: I don't understand why d(a,b) have to be larger than any n > N and if this is true, why we have contradiction?

Comment: @FactorY We proved that for all $n$ we have $d(a,b) \geq n-1$. What does this mean?

Comment: I think it means A is not bounded and I still don't understand what contradiction is.

Comment: @FactorY For all $n >N$ we have $$d(a,b) \geq n-1$$ Take now the limit when $n$ goes to infinity, what do you get?

Comment: We will have d(a,b) is infty. But why it is contradict?

Comment: @FactorY Because by definition any metric only takes finite values. Note that if you allow $d$ take infinite values, the statement and any other result about boundedness trivially fails far the discrete "metric" $d(x,y)=\infty$ whenever when $x \neq y$.