# Is a sequential compact set bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm now learning functional analysis and I already know that, in mathematical analysis, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a bounded set $A$ must be a sequential compact set, i.e. any sequence $\{x_n\}\subset A$ must have a convergent sub-sequence. This is guaranteed by Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem. However, I wonder if the reverse is true, i.e. is a sequential compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set necessarily? If it is true, how to prove it? Thanks for any kind help!

Comment: You could try to show that if $A$ is unbounded, then there exists a sequence in $A$ with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every sequentially compact set is closed and bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226416/every-sequentially-compact-set-is-closed-and-bounded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $A$ is not bounded. Then there is no $r$ such that for each $x \in A$ it holds that $\lVert x \rVert \leq r$; or equivalently, for each $r>0$, there exists $x_r$ with $\lVert x_r \rVert> r$. This defines a sequence $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R^n, n\mapsto x_n$.

By assumption, $(x_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence, so without loss of generality, assume $(x_n)_n$ converges to some point $x$.
Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$, such that for all $n>N$ we have
$$\epsilon>\lVert x- x_n \rVert \ge | \lVert x \rVert - \lVert x_n  \rVert |\enspace.$$
In particular, we can choose $n > \lVert x \rVert +1$, such that $\lVert x_n  \rVert > \lVert x \rVert +1$.
Thus
$\epsilon> \lVert x_n \rVert - \lVert x  \rVert >1$; a contradiction to $\epsilon$ being arbitrary.

Comment: Oh yea thanks a lot!!! BTW I just read a functional analysis text book and it says that a sequencial compact set is not just "bounded". Morever, it is  "completely bounded".  That will also answer my previous question.

Comment: @Scanners Glad I could help. You probably mean "totally bounded". I would advise to look at the proof of sequ. compact -> totally bounded, as it is quite natural and illustrates  well how to tackle such problems. Btw, I would appreciate, if you mark the answer as accepted.